# Showing that $T+S$ is firmly nonexpansive

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Show that $T+S$ is firmly nonexpansive considering that $T$ and $S$ are firmly nonexpansive mappings from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$.

**Definition:** We say that $F$ is firmly nonexpansive if: $$\|F(x)-F(y)\|^2+\|(I-F)(x)-(I-F)(y)\|^2\le \|x-y\|^2$$

Comment: It is false. Let $T = S = I$. Then $T+S = 2I$ which once you plug in you see that is not firmly nonexpansive. Do you perhaps mean to consider $\frac12(T+S)$? In which case the desired conclusion follows from triangle inequality applied many times.

Comment: So how am I suppose to show that , Z=T(2S−I)+I−S is firmly nonexpansive?
I know that , 2S-1 and I-S are firmly non expansive . So firmly nonexpansive of a firmly nonexpansive is firmly nonexpansive??

Comment: Huh? What does your last comment have to do with the question you asked above?

Comment: I know that 2S-I and I-S are firmly nonexpansive . I thought maybe 'nonexpansive expansion of a nonexpansive function is nonexpansive' and  'sum of two nonexpansive functions are nonexpansive' , so I can say that Z i nonexpansive too.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the question you actually want to ask, not the intermediate step (which is not true by my first comment).

Comment: @Willie That would create a duplicate, or rather triplicate, of the OP's earlier question.

Comment: Yea , I've asked this question before , but it's a while I couldn't solve it

Comment: In which case I'll copy my comment as an answer. I'll look at the other one in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

[copied from comment]

It is false. Let $T = S = I$. Then $T+S = 2I$ which once you plug in you see that is not firmly nonexpansive. Do you perhaps mean to consider $\frac12(T+S)$? In which case the desired conclusion follows from triangle inequality applied many times.